# Error in util.java in facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook

I am integrating facebook with android.when i give referance to the facebook sdk then my project work fine,but when i close the ecllipse and reopen the ecllipse then error in util.java in facebook sdk project.why ?
thanks........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes eclipse just get messed at startup. Nothing is like cleaning and building after opening eclipse and before getting started to work.

Comment: You clean and build when you open eclipse and get started to work. Personnaly, I really don't mind, I would not trust any IDE to build my project by itself. :)

Comment: My pleasure. If you think this answer can be useful for others or it was for you, accept the answer please.